# Xcode 11 Swift5 Macos adding storyboard segue creates unwanted triggered action

Tags: macos, segue, swift5, xcode11

I have migrated my MacOS app to Xcode 11 and Swift 5. All is (was) well. However, I am trying to add a segue in the storyboard and when I do it automatically creates a new Connection that is an action. I am coming from an NSTableview where I want to double-click on a row and in that way trigger a different view controller (pre-defined) to open and I pass the selectedrow from the tableview in order to view or edit the detailed record. If I delete the Triggered Segues action it physically removes the segue. Having single action segue trigger as soon as I click on the tableview is NOT what I want.

[image]

I can however add a doubleAction under Sent Actions in order to make the double click on table rows work. I have perhaps 6 other tables that I doubleclick rows and in that was trigger other segues. All of those segues do not have the triggered segue single action as they were added before Xcode 11. I am a little worried that if a touch those segues in the storyboard that the system will force a triggered action on them.

The example "Connection" shown above works fine except that I get an error every time I click on a tableview row. This does not crash the app but it cannot be good.

I do not want a single click on the tableview to perform any function.

How can I removed the Triggered Seque action without the segue itself being removed?

Or, how can I add some code to stop this error:

adeLog[33872:23184897] -[TradeLog.ViewController perform:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102824600
2021-03-23 11:42:44.576862-0400 TradeLog[33872:23184897] [General] -[TradeLog.ViewController perform:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x102824600
2021-03-23 11:42:44.577886-0400 TradeLog[33872:23184897] [General] (
0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff443319ad __exceptionPreprocess + 256
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff6ea62a17 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff443ab7f4 -[NSObject(NSObject) __retain_OA] + 0
3   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff442d381f ***forwarding*** + 1485
4   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff442d31c8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
5   AppKit                              0x00007fff41b62644 -[NSApplication(NSResponder) sendAction:to:from:] + 312
6   AppKit                              0x00007fff41bcc992 -[NSControl sendAction:to:] + 86
7   AppKit                              0x00007fff41c2198f -[NSTableView _sendAction:to:row:column:] + 121
8   AppKit                              0x00007fff41c1ff45 -[NSTableView mouseDown:] + 7381
9   AppKit                              0x00007fff41aa5937 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _handleMouseDownEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 5724
10  AppKit                              0x00007fff419dc1a6 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) _reallySendEvent:isDelayedEvent:] + 2295
11  AppKit                              0x00007fff419db667 -[NSWindow(NSEventRouting) sendEvent:] + 478
12  AppKit                              0x00007fff4187ae4b -[NSApplication(NSEvent) sendEvent:] + 331
13  AppKit                              0x00007fff418695c0 -[NSApplication run] + 755
14  AppKit                              0x00007fff41858ac8 NSApplicationMain + 777
15  TradeLog                            0x00000001001c0ead main + 13
16  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff702313d5 start + 1
17  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3 so

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question which I will explain. In the Interface Builder when creating the segue I was errantly connecting a specific tabelview within the scene it belongs to. All of the previous segues I had created which worked in the past had the source for the segue as being linked to the scene. When this is done the segue is setup as a "manual" segue.

The scene shows the manual segues....

[image]

And the tableview Triggered Seque action is now gone.

[image]

The application is working for me now without throwing errors.